# predict.lm with newdata

Tags: r

I've built an `lm` model without using the `data=` parameter:

```
m1 <- lm( mdldvlp.trim$y ~  gc.pc$scores[,1] + gc.pc$scores[,2] + gc.pc$scores[,3] + 
                            gc.pc$scores[,4] + gc.pc$scores[,5] + gc.pc$scores[,6] + predict(gc.tA))
```

Now I'd like to predict `m1` using `newdata` and so name my new data.frame to match the variables used in the `lm()` call above.

With `newComps` as my new `gc.pc` (which, like the `gc.tA` prediction, were predicted using the new data.frame without any issues), I've tried

```
newD <- data.frame( newComps[1:100,1:6] ,
                    predict(gc.tA , newdata = mdldvlp[1:100,predKept]))


names(newD) <- names(m1$coefficients)[-1]
names(newD) <- names(m1$model)[-1]

names(newD) <- c( "gc.pc$scores[, 1]" , "gc.pc$scores[, 2]" , "gc.pc$scores[, 3]" , 
                  "gc.pc$scores[, 4]" , "gc.pc$scores[, 5]" , "gc.pc$scores[, 6]" , 
                  "predict(gc.tA)" )
names(newD) <- c( "gc.pc$scores[,1]" , "gc.pc$scores[,2]" , "gc.pc$scores[,3]" , 
                  "gc.pc$scores[,4]" , "gc.pc$scores[,5]" , "gc.pc$scores[,6]" , 
                  "predict(gc.tA)" )
```

Unfortunately, `predict.lm` does not accept the naming strategies above and returns the dreaded `newdata` warning along with the predictions from the original data.frame that built `m1`:

```
Warning message:
'newdata' had 100 rows but variable(s) found have 1414 rows
```

How should I name the `newD` columns to make the `predict` call work? Thanks.

The code below recreates the issue:

```
    require(rpart)

    set.seed(123)
    X <- matrix(runif(200) , 20 , 10)
    gc.pc <- princomp(X)
    y <- runif(20)
    mdldvlp.trim <- data.frame(y,X)
    names(mdldvlp.trim) <- c("y",paste("x",1:10,sep=""))
    predKept <- paste("x",1:10,sep="")

    gc.tA <- rpart( y ~ . , data = mdldvlp.trim)

    m1 <- lm( mdldvlp.trim$y ~  gc.pc$scores[,1] + gc.pc$scores[,2] + gc.pc$scores[,3] + 
                                gc.pc$scores[,4] + gc.pc$scores[,5] + gc.pc$scores[,6] + predict(gc.tA))

    mdldvlp <- data.frame(matrix(runif(2000) , 200 , 10))
    names(mdldvlp) <- predKept

    newComps <- predict( gc.pc , newdata=mdldvlp )

    newD <- data.frame( newComps[1:100,1:6] ,
                        predict(gc.tA , newdata = mdldvlp[1:100,predKept]))

# enter newD naming strategy here

    predict( m1 , newdata=newD )
```

### 4/20 Follow up:

Thanks all for your answers. I understand things would be easier by first creating a data.frame with properly named predictors. I understand that. My question is if the modeling data frame does indeed evaluate to a data frame with variables named `gc.pc$scores[,1]` etc. then why won't the naming 'strategies' used above work with `predict.lm`? In other words, does `lm` really evaluate its modeling data frame with `gc.pc$scores[,1]` and so on? If it did, wouldn't the renaming strategies above work in `predict.lm`?

Comment: Would it be possible to combine `mdldvlp.trim$y`, the `gc.pc$scores`, and `predict(gc.tA)` into one data.frame to use when creating `m1`? Then you could use the `data` argument in `lm`, write a formula including only `names(data)` and avoid giving `newD` potentially invalid names.

Answer (score 8):

You are abusing the formula notation and it is this that is causing you problems. Essentially your formula:

```
m1 <- lm( mdldvlp.trim$y ~  gc.pc$scores[,1] + gc.pc$scores[,2] + 
                            gc.pc$scores[,3] + gc.pc$scores[,4] + 
                            gc.pc$scores[,5] + gc.pc$scores[,6] + 
                            predict(gc.tA))
```

will evaluate to a data frame with variables named `gc.pc$scores[,1]` etc. When you use `predict()` it will look for variables with these same names in the object passed to the `newdata` argument.

Ideally, you'd create a data object with all the variables you want included in them with appropriate names, eg:

```
fitData <- data.frame(mdldvlp.trim$y, gc.pc$scores[, 1:6], predict(gc.tA))
names(fitData) <- c("trimY", paste("scores", 1:6, sep = ""), "preds")
```

and then fit the model via:

```
m1 <- lm(trimY ~ ., data = fitData)
```

New predictions can be made from the model by providing a data frame with the same names as used to fit the model. Hence using your `newD`:

```
newD <- data.frame(newComps[1:100,1:6] ,
                   predict(gc.tA , newdata = mdldvlp[1:100,predKept]))
names(newD) <- c(paste("scores", 1:6, sep = ""), "preds")
```

and then `predict()`

```
predict(m1 , newdata=newD)
```

### Full example

```
require(rpart)

set.seed(123)
X <- matrix(runif(200) , 20 , 10)
gc.pc <- princomp(X)
y <- runif(20)
mdldvlp.trim <- data.frame(y,X)
names(mdldvlp.trim) <- c("y",paste("x",1:10,sep=""))
predKept <- paste("x",1:10,sep="")

gc.tA <- rpart( y ~ . , data = mdldvlp.trim)
fitData <- data.frame(mdldvlp.trim$y, gc.pc$scores[, 1:6], predict(gc.tA))
names(fitData) <- c("trimY", paste("scores", 1:6, sep = ""), "preds")
m1 <- lm(trimY ~ ., data = fitData)
mdldvlp <- data.frame(matrix(runif(2000) , 200 , 10))
names(mdldvlp) <- predKept

newComps <- predict( gc.pc , newdata=mdldvlp )
newD <- data.frame(newComps[1:100,1:6] ,
                   predict(gc.tA , newdata = mdldvlp[1:100,predKept]))
names(newD) <- c(paste("scores", 1:6, sep = ""), "preds")
predict(m1 , newdata=newD)
```

Comment: If the formula evaluates to a data frame with variables named `gc.pc$scores[,1]` and so on, why does the call to `predict.lm` fail when these same var names are used? How do data.frame variable name choices abuse the formula notation?

Comment: @M.Dimo I meant you are abusing the formula notation by using constructs like `obj$var` in a formula. You should use `var` in the formula and pass `obj` as the `data` argument. These things work using non-standard evaluation rules; they determine how you /should/ write a formula so that `lm()` and `predict` work. You are on your own if you go off piste and things don't work. I need to look at your example more closely to be clear I understand and can explain why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar issue in the past - I think I resolved it by giving my variables names instead of referring to a column number. e.g. Don't use gc.pc[,1], but convert the gc.pc matrix to a dataframe and add names to the columns ("PC1", "PC2", ... etc.). Then make sure that your newdata also uses these names (in a dataframe as well).

Comment: Thanks all for your answers. I understand things would be easier by first creating a data.frame with properly named predictors. I understand that. My question is if the modeling data frame does evaluate to a data frame with variables named gc.pc$scores[,1] etc. then how do I use this to run predict.lm?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. If my data frame had three or more variables (one outcome and two or more prediction variables), I had no problems when referring to columns by their column number. But, when my data frame had only two variables (one outcome, one predictor), R gave me lots of errors, including `'newdata' had 1 row but variables found have xx rows`

Following Marc in the box's suggestion, I wrote a special case for instances in which the data frame has only two variables, and assigned variable names. This fixed my issue.

To fix my this warning, I rewrote:

```
lr <- lm(train[ , ncol(train)] ~ ., data = train[ , -ncol(train)])
```

as:

```
if(ncol(train) == 2) {
    colnames(train) <- c('var1','var2')
    colnames(test) <- c('var1','var2')
    lr <- lm(var2 ~ var1, data = train)
} else if (ncol(train) > 2) {
    lr <- lm(train[ , ncol(train)] ~ ., data = train[ , -ncol(train)])
}
```